# probability random sample mean and variance

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Suppose also that $\nu:=E[(X_1 - \mu)^4] < \infty $.

(a) Find the mean and variance of $ V_n= \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^\infty (X_i -\mu)^2 $.

(b) Now assume that the mean $\mu$ is known. Using the weak law of large numbers, explain why $V_n$ is a good estimator of the variance $\sigma^2$.

For part (a) can I write let $V_i = (X_i -\mu)^2$ and then use the theorem for the expectation and variance of a sample mean to say the expectation of $ V_n$ is $\mu$ and the variance is $\sigma^2$? This seems like it cannot be right but I am unsure.

For part (b) will I have to use Chebyshev's inequality at some point? Is that where the fact that $\nu:=E[(X_1 - \mu)^4] < \infty $ comes in?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For (a), consider explicitly expanding the sum, i.e. $\sum (X_i-\mu)^2 = \sum (X_i^2 + \mu^2 - 2\mu x_i
)$

Comment: @gt6989b doing that should I eventually get to the point where I have $$ E[V_n]= \frac{\mu^2}{n} \sum_{i=0}^\infty E[X_i^2-2 \mu X_i] $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), the idea of looking at the random variables $(X_i-\mu)^2$ is a good one. The choice $V_i$ for the name is potentially confusing.

Let's write $Y_i=(X_i-\mu)^2$. Then $V_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(Y_1+ Y_2+\cdots+Y_n\right)$.

The $Y_i$ are independent, so we will be able to find the mean and variance of $V_n$ once we know the mean and variance of the $Y_i$.

The mean of $Y_i$ should be easy to recognize, from the *definition* of the variance of $X_i$.

For the variance of the $Y_i$, we need to compute $E\left[(X_i-\mu)^4\right]-\left(E\left[(X_i-\mu)^2\right]\right)^2$.
This is where $\nu$ comes into the game.

Now that we have found the mean and variance of the $Y_i$, calculate the mean and variance of $V_n$. The mean turns out to be $\sigma^2$. The variance will be something with an $n$ in the denominator. So for large $n$ the variance of $V_n$ is small. Then you can use the Chebyshev Inequality to draw conclusions. But depending on what theorems you have available to quote, you may not need to use the Chebyshev Inequality explicitly.

Comment: for some reason I am having trouble seeing why the mean of $Y_i$ is obvious based on the definition of the variance of $X_i$

Comment: The usual definition of the variance of a random variable $X$ is $\text{Var}(X)=E[(X-\mu)^2]$, where $\mu$ is the mean of $X$. A useful shortcut formula for computing the variance is $E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=E[X^2]-\mu^2$. But the basic definition is the one I gave first. It is the "average value of" the square of the distance of $X$ from the mean.